# Create unique logfile name per VM for logback

Tags: java, logback

We have a rich client that may be started multiple times on a platform. What is the best way to configure logback so that each one gets a logfile of its own, without resorting to millisecond timestamps or VMIDs. I'm searching for a pattern feature comparable to Java logging "%u" (unique file name).

Comment: Hi mtraut, have you solved this? I'm in need if the solution... Tkx

Comment: Nope - i think still best you can achieve is using millis in the file name pattern. I thought a minute or two about implementing the feature, but found the code extremely unfriendly for simple enhancements.

Comment: yes thats what I did... Thx